# How to find the min value of a sequence of negative numbers?

Tags: matlab, min, negative-number

I have a vector of negative values like this:

```
values = [-15,  -6.45,  -3.75, -5.55, -2.40]
```

i want to know which of these is the smallest and the corresponding index. I try using `min` function but i ran into this error:

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

How can i solve this annoying problem?

Comment: Do you have a variable called `min` in the workspace? Make sure, `which min` returns `built-in` (which means it is a built-in function) and not `min is a variable`

Comment: NO! I'm using the min buil-in matlab function but it returns this error!

Comment: no variable is called min :/

Comment: Strange.. Can you edit your question to include how exactly you call `min`?

Comment: what does `which min` return?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to use the direct output of `min` to access an entry in an array. The return value of `min` is the actual minimum value not the index in the array.

To get the value and the index try using the following code:

```
values = [-15,  -6.45,  -3.75, -5.55, -2.40];
[minval,minindex] = min(values)
```

This will return `minval = -15` and `minindex = 1`. With `minindex` you can address an entry in an array. For example in the `values`-array:

```
values(minindex)
```

This returns of course `-15`.

Comment: @madmad: Was my answer helpful? If yes, it would be nice to accept it as 'accepted answer'. Thanks...